# Switching from rvm to system ruby made me lose access to gems

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rvm, bundle

I switched from rvm to using system ruby today, and I had to rerun bundle in my project directories which wasn't surprising.  But after doing that, I was no longer able to access gems by command line.

For example: rspec spec no longer works even in a project that has rspec in its bundle.  When I check the location of rspec it is still in a .rvm directory:

```
$ gem which rspec
/Users/jeremysmith/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-2.6.0/lib/rspec.rb
```

And I've checked $GEM_HOME but it isn't set to anything.

UPDATE:

I switched back to system ruby by running:

```
rvm use system
```

And when I try

```
bundle exec rspec spec
```

I get another gem that can't be found even though it's installed:

```
uninitialized constant Object::Rack (NameError)
```

RVM debug:

```
system:

rvm 1.2.8 by Wayne E. Seguin (wayneeseguin@gmail.com) [http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/]

system:

  system:
    uname:       "Darwin JJSMacPro.local 11.0.0 Darwin Kernel Version 11.0.0: Sat Jun 18 12:56:35 PDT 2011; root:xnu-1699.22.73~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64"
    bash:        "/bin/bash => GNU bash, version 3.2.48(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin11)"
    zsh:         "/bin/zsh => zsh 4.3.11 (i386-apple-darwin11.0)"

  rvm:
    version:      "rvm 1.2.8 by Wayne E. Seguin (wayneeseguin@gmail.com) [http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/]"

  homes:
    gem:          "not set"
    ruby:         "not set"

  binaries:
    ruby:         "/usr/bin/ruby"
    irb:          "/usr/bin/irb"
    gem:          "/usr/bin/gem"
    rake:         "/usr/bin/rake"

  environment:
    PATH:         "/sw/bin:/sw/sbin:/sw2/bin:/sw2/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin:/Developer/usr/bin/:/usr/local/sbin:/Users/jeremysmith/.rvm/bin:/Users/jeremysmith/.rvm/bin"
    GEM_HOME:     ""
    GEM_PATH:     ""
    MY_RUBY_HOME: ""
    IRBRC:        ""
    RUBYOPT:      ""
    gemset:       ""
  PATH:
/sw/bin:/sw/sbin:/sw2/bin:/sw2/sbin:/usr/bin
  uname -a: Darwin JJSMacPro.local 11.0.0 Darwin Kernel Version 11.0.0: Sat Jun 18 12:56:35 PDT 2011; root:xnu-1699.22.73~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
  permissions: /Users/jeremysmith/.rvm:
total 32
drwxr-xr-x  23 jeremysmith  staff   782 Aug 14 13:52 .
drwxr-xr-x+ 94 jeremysmith  staff  3196 Aug 12 10:19 ..
-rw-r--r--   1 jeremysmith  staff   566 Mar  3 11:34 LICENCE
-rw-r--r--   1 jeremysmith  staff  7986 Mar  3 11:34 README
-rw-r--r--   1 jeremysmith  staff     6 Mar  3 11:34 VERSION
drwxr-xr-x   5 jeremysmith  staff   170 Aug 14 13:45 archives
drwxr-xr-x  32 jeremysmith  staff  1088 Aug 14 14:40 bin
drwxr-xr-x   8 jeremysmith  staff   272 Aug 14 14:40 config
drwxr-xr-x   5 jeremysmith  staff   170 Aug 14 13:51 environments
drwxr-xr-x   3 jeremysmith  staff   102 Feb 19 15:36 examples
drwxr-xr-x  10 jeremysmith  staff   340 Aug 14 14:36 gems
drwxr-xr-x   8 jeremysmith  staff   272 Feb 19 15:36 gemsets
drwxr-xr-x  39 jeremysmith  staff  1326 Feb 19 15:36 help
drwxr-xr-x   4 jeremysmith  staff   136 Feb 19 15:36 lib
drwxr-xr-x   8 jeremysmith  staff   272 Aug 14 14:36 log
drwxr-xr-x   5 jeremysmith  staff   170 Feb 19 15:36 patches
drwxr-xr-x   3 jeremysmith  staff   102 Aug 14 13:52 repos
drwxr-xr-x   6 jeremysmith  staff   204 Aug 14 14:40 rubies
drwxr-xr-x  56 jeremysmith  staff  1904 Mar  3 11:34 scripts
drwxr-xr-x   8 jeremysmith  staff   272 Aug 14 14:36 src
drwxr-xr-x   2 jeremysmith  staff    68 Mar  3 11:36 tmp
drwxr-xr-x   4 jeremysmith  staff   136 Aug  9 21:01 user
drwxr-xr-x   7 jeremysmith  staff   238 Aug 14 13:51 wrappers

/Users/jeremysmith/.rvm/rubies:
total 8
drwxr-xr-x   6 jeremysmith  staff  204 Aug 14 14:40 .
drwxr-xr-x  23 jeremysmith  staff  782 Aug 14 13:52 ..
lrwxr-xr-x   1 jeremysmith  staff   46 Mar  3 11:42 default -> /Users/jeremysmith/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180
drwxr-xr-x   4 jeremysmith  staff  136 Aug 14 13:50 macruby-0.9-HEAD
drwxr-xr-x   4 jeremysmith  staff  136 Aug 14 14:36 macruby-0.9-trunk
drwxr-xr-x   8 jeremysmith  staff  272 Jun 11 23:46 ruby-1.9.2-p180

  uname -r: 11.0.0
  uname -m: x86_64
  sw_vers: ProductName: Mac OS X,ProductVersion:    10.7,BuildVersion:  11A511,
  ARCHFLAGS: 
  LDFLAGS: 
  CFLAGS: 
  /Developer/SDKs/*:MacOSX10.6.sdk,MacOSX10.7.sdk,

/Users/jeremysmith/.bashrc:

/Users/jeremysmith/.bash_profile:
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"  # This loads RVM into a shell session.
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
/Users/jeremysmith/.rvm/config/alias \(filtered\):
default=ruby-1.9.2-p180

/Users/jeremysmith/.rvm/config/db \(filtered\):
#General
niceness=0
# Rubies
interpreter=ruby
ruby_version=1.8.7
ruby_configure_flags=--enable-shared --disable-install-doc
ruby_patchlevel=299
ruby_configure=--enable-shared
ruby_repo_url=https://github.com/ruby/ruby.git
ruby_1.0_url=ftp://ftp.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/1.0
ruby_1.2_url=ftp://ftp.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/1.2
ruby_1.3_url=ftp://ftp.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/1.3
ruby_1.4_url=ftp://ftp.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/1.4
ruby_1.5_url=ftp://ftp.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/1.5
ruby_1.6_url=ftp://ftp.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/1.6
ruby_1.7_url=ftp://ftp.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/1.7
ruby_1.8_url=ftp://ftp.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/1.8
ruby_1.9_url=ftp://ftp.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/1.9
ruby_2.0_url=ftp://ftp.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/2.0
ruby_1.9.1_patch_level=431
ruby_1.9.2_patch_level=180
ruby_1.8.5_patch_level=231
ruby_1.8.6_patch_level=420
ruby_1.8.7_patch_level=334
rubygems_1.3.5_url=http://rubyforge.org/frs/download.php/60718
rubygems_1.3.6_url=http://rubyforge.org/frs/download.php/69365
rubygems_1.3.7_url=http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/src
rubygems_1.4.1_url=http://rubyforge.org/frs/download.php/73779
rubygems_1.4.2_url=http://rubyforge.org/frs/download.php/73882
rubygems_1.5.0_url=http://rubyforge.org/frs/download.php/74140
rubygems_1.5.1_url=http://rubyforge.org/frs/download.php/74220
rubygems_1.5.2_url=http://rubyforge.org/frs/download.php/74234
rubygems_1.5.3_url=http://rubyforge.org/frs/download.php/74343
rubygems_1.6.0_url=http://rubyforge.org/frs/download.php/74374
rubygems_repo_url=git://github.com/rubygems/rubygems.git
rubygems_version=1.6.0
rbx_version=head
rbx_1.0.0_patch_level=20100514
rbx_1.0.1_patch_level=20100603
rbx_1.1.0_patch_level=20100923
rbx_1.1.1_patch_level=20101116
rbx_1.2.0_patch_level=20101221
rbx_1.2.1_patch_level=20110215
rbx_1.2.2_patch_level=20110222
rbx_url=http://asset.rubini.us
rubinius_repo_url=git://github.com/evanphx/rubinius.git
ree_version=1.8.7
ree_configure_flags=--dont-install-useful-gems
ree_1.8.6_patch_level=20090610
ree_1.8.6_url=http://rubyforge.org/frs/download.php/58677
ree_1.8.6_repo_url=git://github.com/FooBarWidget/rubyenterpriseedition.git
ree_1.8.7_url=http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/src
ree_1.8.7_repo_url=git://github.com/FooBarWidget/rubyenterpriseedition187-330
ree_1.8.7_patch_level=2011.03
jruby_version=1.5.6
jruby_repo_url=git://github.com/jruby/jruby.git
jruby_url=http://jruby.org.s3.amazonaws.com/downloads
macruby_version=0.9
macruby_nightly_version=0.10
macruby_url=http://www.macruby.org/files
macruby_repo_url=git://git.macruby.org/macruby/MacRuby.git
macruby_nightly_url=http://www.macruby.org/files/nightlies/macruby_nightly-latest.pkg
maglev_version=25329
maglev_url=http://glass-downloads.gemstone.com/maglev
maglev_repo_url=git://github.com/MagLev/maglev.git
ironruby_version=1.0
ironruby_repo_url=git://github.com/ironruby/ironruby.git
ironruby_1.0_url=http://rubyforge.org/frs/download.php/70179
# Packages
readline_url=ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/readline
libiconv_url=http://ftp.gnu.org/pub/gnu/libiconv
curl_url=http://curl.haxx.se/download
openssl_url=http://www.openssl.org/source
zlib_url=http://www.zlib.net
autoconf_url=ftp.gnu.org/gnu/autoconf
ncurses_url=http://ftp.gnu.org/pub/gnu/ncurses
pkg-config_url=http://pkgconfig.freedesktop.org/releases
gettext_url=ftp://ftp.gnu.org/pub/gnu/gettext
libxml2_url=ftp://xmlsoft.org/libxml2
yaml_url=http://pyyaml.org/download/libyaml
glib_url=http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/gnome/sources/glib/2.23
mono_url=http://ftp.novell.com/pub/mono/sources/mono
llvm_url=https://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/llvm/trunk

gem sources:
http://rubygems.org/
```

Comment: Can you detail your steps for migrating to system Ruby? Also -- to run a binary from a gem that's managed by Bundler, you should [always use](http://yehudakatz.com/2011/05/30/gem-versioning-and-bundler-doing-it-right/) `bundle exec`.

Comment: Hi Brandon, I updated my post to answer your questions.

Comment: Thanks, Jeremy, one more: what is the output of `rvm debug` (and `rvm info` if `rvm debug` doesn't contain it already)

Comment: Yikes that's alot of info!  Thanks for looking at this Brandon.

Comment: First thing I notice is that your RVM is out of date by a few months. Try [updating RVM](http://beginrescueend.com/rvm/upgrading/) and see if that helps at all. It also appears your `.bash_profile` is loading RVM twice; it shouldn't made a difference, but I'd (1) remove the extra line and (2) ensure the remaining line the last item in your `.bash_profile`. There's also `rvm reset`, which reset RVM's options (and makes it forget your `--default` option) you may wish to try.

Comment: Once you switch to the system ruby the gems you installed under RVM rubies **will not be available anywhere else**. That's the purpose of RVM, having **closed** environments that do not affect each other. If you want to access the gems you must be using the Ruby for which you installed them, RVM does not **share** gems between different rubies.

Comment: I'll try those things Brandon thanks.  I wish you guys would post these as answers so I could +1 them :)  Mauricio but I am installing the gems now under the non-RVM ruby, that's why it's confusing to me that they are not showing as available.

Comment: I think the biggest issue is that if I uninstall and then reinstall a gem, it is still going in the RVM folder.

Comment: So I've removed all of the gems in an RVM folder, removed rubygems.rb in the RVM folder, set a new configuration .gemrc in the ~ folder that sets a different install path, and still installing to RVM!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that rubygems was still installed in an .rvm directory. So i tried removing rubygems but I was still getting gem installs placed in an .rvm directory, even after removing all reference to .rvm in my bash files.

But I found out that when I told .rvm to use system ruby, it turns out that my system ruby in /usr/bin still had references back to .rvm.  So I imploded rvm, and built ruby from source, and now everything is working.